# No hints for .js files but for <script> tag in .html

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I just get no code completion for my scripts (.js files) in a project, but inside  tag hints work perfectly.
The only extensions installed are Live Server and Prettier.

What I am talking about is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfXw2.jpg

I tried "JavaScript (ES6) code snippets" and others similar, but still no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VSCode has embedded support for .js files. For vanilla JS no need to install ES6 or whatever.

In VSCode open **Extension** tab (Ctrl + Shift + X), then type **@builtin types**. Enable both. By default first one is disabled.

This solved my problem.

[image: Example of what you should see]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use brackets which has very good completion features. Vscode is also good.